# i have a progress bars its maximum values keep on changing in Angular2 .in service maximum value changes for every bar .Now its working for 100%

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
this.games=[
    {"val":50, "name":"Articlescontributed","max":35},
    {"val":30 ,"name":"Articlesrated", "max":999},
    {"val":20, "name":"Views", "max":35},
    {"val":30, "name":"Ratings", "max":35},
    {"val":20, "name":"Follower", "max":200},
    {"val":17, "name":"Articleviews", "max":200},
    {"val":30, "name":"Comments", "max":500},
    {"val":100, "name":"Comments on Article", "max":100},
    {"val":30, "name":"Profileviews", "max":35},
    {"val":80, "name":"Following", "max":25},
]
```

```html
<div class="pro">
    <div class="pro-bar"  [style.width]="game.val +'%'">
        <span class="tip">{{game.val}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
this.games=[
    {"val":50, "name":"Articlescontributed","max":35},
    {"val":30 ,"name":"Articlesrated", "max":999},
    {"val":20, "name":"Views", "max":35},
    {"val":30, "name":"Ratings", "max":35},
    {"val":20, "name":"Follower", "max":200},
    {"val":17, "name":"Articleviews", "max":200},
    {"val":30, "name":"Comments", "max":500},
    {"val":100, "name":"Comments on Article", "max":100},
    {"val":30, "name":"Profileviews", "max":35},
    {"val":80, "name":"Following", "max":25},
]
```

```html
<div class="pro">
    <div class="pro-bar"  [style.width]="game.val +'%'">
    <span class="tip">{{game.val}}</span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

see in progress "val" indicates how much percentage it will increase
like that for every progress bar max value is not 100%..nw our values works only for 100% not for other values so need assistance

Comment: Share your screenshot and the code where you have used `*ngFor`

Comment: please i edited the html

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `ngStyle` with `%` to set the styles -

```
<div class="pro-bar"  [ngStyle]="{'width.%': game.val}">
```